# Android (JAVA) - CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception

Sometimes when I call cursorToCacheItem application crashes with the error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
com.itirsolutions.cache.BaseCache.cursorToCacheItem(BaseCache.java:131)
com.itirsolutions.cache.BaseCache.get(BaseCache.java:101)
com.itirsolutions.cache.BaseCache.put(BaseCache.java:47)
com.itirsolutions.transactions.UsersInfoCache.put(UsersInfoCache.java:27)
etc..
```

My cursorToCacheItem function:

```
private CacheItem cursorToCacheItem(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getColumnCount() == 0)
        return null;

    // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? After checking there, why does not it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  this

```
   if (cursor == null || cursor.getColumnCount() == 0)
```

to

```
if (!(cursor.moveToFirst()) || cursor.getCount() ==0){
```

Answer (score 2):

Put:

```
if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0)
```

instead of

```
if (cursor == null || cursor.getColumnCount() == 0).
```

You were checking number of columns instead of number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Write `cursor.moveToFirst()` before querying the cursor. It is by default at its last position.

Then you can loop through the contents of it, using `While(cursor.isAfterLast)` and in the loop body use `cursor.moveToNext()`.